# Renumber figures as they appear in text

Tags: floats

I have two questions:

1. When I use `figure*`, LaTeX sometimes places the figure before its predecessor. Is there a way to automatically number the figures as they appear in the text?
2. On the other hand, is there a way to enforce the figures order? I tried to put `\FloatBarrier` before each figure, but it messed up the document. I don't mind it to float past a specific point, but I do want it to keep them in order.

Comment: When you use `*`, you are letting `LaTeX` manage the placement.  That is, you have given up control of order.  `\Floatbarrier` is generally used to stop figures from moving out of a `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, etc. but not order since `LaTeX` is making the best use of space.  The figures are automatically numbered.  What do you mean by is there a way to automatically number the figures as they appear?

Comment: Latex decided on a certain order of figures: 4,1,3,2. I have no problem with the order or placement of the figures themselves, but I still would like to figure counter to increase monotonically, i.e. set a different numbering to the figures: 1,2,3,4.

Comment: @ZoharLevi basically it's a bug, but we can't change the default figure placement as it would potentially affect every latex document. That is why the core latex distribution has the `fixltx2e` package that allows people to opt-in to certain fixed behaviour, without forcing incompatible changes on the existing archive of latex documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

double and single column figures are kept in the correct order if you load the `fixltx2e` package.

**Update**

The ordering is correct by default for LaTeX releases from 2015/01/01.

Comment: Works like magic!

Answer (score 0):

You can "*force*" the figure placement by adding:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    ...
\end{figure}
```

You can also use `[H]` as suggested in this post: [Similar post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text?rq=1)

For more detailed information on figure placement, see post: [More info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: The main effect of `[ht!]` is to prevent the use of float pages, so make it rather likely that that figure and all following ones go to the end of the document.

Comment: I think it's the other way around... Since `[ht!]` prevents the use of float pages, the figure appears as close as possible to where it's called in the text.

Comment: No. That's not how it works.

Comment: My bad in that case ... But that's the experience I've had so far when using it ...

Comment: well because you use `!` it masks the effect, but stopping `p` does not make `t` or `b` more likely so if you have a float that can not be placed `t`, stopping `p` just makes it go to the end.

Comment: This question isn't about forcing figure placement. It's about preventing one and two column figures from getting out of order in a two column document.